# How to validate multiselect box in codeigniter4

Tags: validation, multi-select, codeigniter-4

I am using a multi-select box to select all employees assigned to a project:

```
 <select name="int_employeeID[]" id="int_employeeID" class="form-control" multiple>
                        <?php foreach ($employee as $e) : ?>
                        <option value="<?= $e['id']; ?>"><?= $e['vchr_employeeName']; ?> : <?= $e['vchr_CDIT_employeeID'] ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

How would I validate it in server side using codeigniter4?
In codeigniter3 I validate it as :

```
 if (empty($post['int_employeeID'])) {
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('int_employeeID', 'Employee Name', 'required',array('required' =>'Select at least one Employee'));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Validating Keys that are Arrays](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/libraries/validation.html#validating-keys-that-are-arrays)

> "dot array syntax” can also be useful when you have single dimension
> array data. For example, data returned by multi select dropdown:
>
> ```php
> <?php
>
> /*
>  * The data to test:
>  * [
>  *     'user_ids' => [
>  *         1,
>  *         2,
>  *         3,
>  *     ]
>  * ]
>  */
>
> // Rule
> $validation->setRules([
>     'user_ids.*' => 'required',
> ]);
> ```

Comment: So In my case i need just to replace user_ids with int_employeeID, right?

Comment: i want to validate it as numeric also